# How can I echo out all values associated with the email in my table

Tags: php

I have a table with several columns. A user logs in with a unique email and imputs values which are in turn stored in the mysql table. How can I echo out all these values associated with the user's email? I have tried a for loop, using  the table ID values, which works when you increment through consercutive values, which isn't the case with the table.

```
//Here's my code so far:
$rownum = "SELECT * FROM tablename";


$rowrun =  mysql_query($rownum, $connect); //    simply querying here
//$connect is the link to server nd database.

$rowcount=mysql_num_rows($rowrun);//getting.   number of table rows, to be used in forloop

for($c=1; $c<=$rowcount; $c++){
//$c will be the stand-in for ID values from the table.   which I'm using to loop.

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE.    emai='$email'; //all users will be identified by email

$row = mysql_fetch_array($rowrun); //getting array. of associated column values

$grades = $row['grades'];
$classroom = $row['classroom'];
$ID= $row['ID']; 

if(!empty($grades)&&!empty($classroom)){

    echo "learner from class".$classroom."has.   gotten".$grade."%"
    //here I want all display grades and classsroom.  number obtained from the mysql table associated with user's email
    }
}
```

?>
Here's the problem: the loop works when I have an initial value for $c and the values are consercutive. But the values on the table won't be arranged consercutively and hence the loop won't increment desirably ( $c++). Whats more, the initial ID (primary auto incrementing column) value will keep changing depending on the user.

What are my options here? Foreach loop? While loop? Select by group?
To print or echo out all values associated with the user's login email

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run one query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email = '$email'"
```

This will return all matches, and then you can run this query and loop through the returned data (if any)

```
$resultset = $conn->query($sql);

if ($resultset->num_rows > 0) {
 // echo data
} else {
 // no data returned
}
```